# Has anyone got Sikuli running on Android Emulators in Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: firebase-test-lab

We have a hybrid app product that runs on a Nexus 7. We have been using Sikuli to test it on a local machine and were looking for other options.

Has anyone got Sikuli running in Firebase Test Lab?

Comment: If you want to open a general discussion, Stack Overflow isn't the right place for it.  Try using the #test-lab channel in the Firebase Slack instead.  https://firebase.community/